# Fancybox erroneously changing height based on screen size

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

I have a fancybox with the height and width set in pixels.  The code is:

```
$("#join").fancybox({
    overlayOpacity      : 0.8, // Set opacity to 0.8
    overlayColor        : "#000000", // Set color to Black
    padding         : 0,
    'width'         : 305,
    'height'        : 677,
    'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
    'transitionOut'     : 'elastic',
    'type'          : 'iframe',
});
```

The height and width of the fancybox are exactly matching the content inside the fancybox, so there --should-- be no vertical or horizontal scroll bars.

When I open the fancybox on my Desktop computer, everything shows fine -- no scroll bars. However, when I open the fancybox on my laptop computer (smaller screen size), the fancybox has a vertical scroll bar requiring me to scroll down to see the rest of the fancybox content.  The width is fine -- no horizontal scroll bar appears.  Even though the height is set to 677px, it seems to be showing smaller on my laptop computer.

To see this actually happening live, go to www.mytrailapp.com and click the join button (upper right corner).  The fancybox popup should have no scroll bars, but seems to have a vertical scroll bar on my laptop computer.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add the line `autoScale: false,` to your jQuery code:

```
$("#join").fancybox({
autoScale : false,
overlayOpacity      : 0.8, // Set opacity to 0.8
overlayColor        : "#000000", // Set color to Black
padding         : 0,
'width'         : 305,
'height'        : 677,
'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
'transitionOut'     : 'elastic',
'type'          : 'iframe',
});
```

I think that is the behaviour you want if the screen is shorter than the content.

Comment: +1 : assuming the OP is using fancybox v1.3.4 this should be the correct answer (and use mine for further reference on v2.x)

Answer (score 0):

If using fancybox v1.3.4 set `autoScale` to `false` :

```
$("#join").fancybox({
    autoScale: false, 
    // your other API options
});
```

If using fancybox v2.x set `fitToView` to `false` :

```
$("#join").fancybox({
    fitToView : false,
    // your other API options
});
```